# Why I can't remove item from ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I filled some `ObservableCollection<Employe>` collection:

```
// Program.Data.Employees - it is ObservableCollection<Employe>.
Program.Data.Employees.Add(new Employe() { Name="Roman", Patronymic="Petrovich", Surname="Ivanov" });
Program.Data.Employees.Add(new Employe() { Name = "Oleg", Patronymic = "Vladimirovich", Surname = "Trofimov" });
Program.Data.Employees.Add(new Employe() { Name = "Anton", Patronymic = "Igorevich", Surname = "Kuznetcov" });
```

In other place of my code I try to remove some item from this collection:

```
// Program.Data.Employees - it is ObservableCollection<Employe>.
Employe x = Program.Data.Employees.First(n => n.Guid == emp.Guid); // x is not null.
Int32 index = Program.Data.Employees.IndexOf(x); // I got -1. Why?
Boolean result = Program.Data.Employees.Remove(x); // I got 'false', and item is not removed. Why?
// But this works fine:
Program.Data.Employees.Clear();
```

I can clear collection, but I can't remove necessary item. Why it happens?

## UPD: `Equals` method of my `Employe` class

```
public bool Equals(Employe other) {
    return
    other.Guid == this.Guid &&
    String.Equals(other.Name, this.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
    String.Equals(other.Patronymic == this.Patronymic, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
    String.Equals(other.Surname == this.Surname, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
    other.Sex == this.Sex &&
    String.Equals(other.Post == this.Post, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: Is Employe (sic) a struct or class?

Comment: @alexw `public sealed class Employe : INotifyPropertyChanged, ICloneable, IEquatable<Employe>`.

Comment: If index is -1 and result is false then x is not part of the collection. What happens if you call FirstOrDefault() instead? What happens if you call Program.Data.Employees.Where(n => n.Guid == emp.Guid).FirstOrDefault() ??

Comment: `If index is -1 and result is false then x is not part of the collection.` I know but I got value in `x` variable through `First` method.

Comment: Looks like you are defined Equals method wrong. Check is x.Equals(x) returns true

Comment: Yes but why _isn't_ it part of the collection? Has the collection been modified? Have you tried the other methods to confirm this behaviour?

Comment: @kiwaa Looks like you are correct. He did implement IEquatable<Employe>.

Comment: I add "UPD" in my first message.

Comment: `String.Equals(other.Surname == this.Surname, ...)` is very wrong.

Comment: @Markus Jarderot I am a blind donkey! Yes, I find it now too :) Now all works. I wrote at night a code and copied by inertia. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried the following code to reproduce your error:

```
class Employee
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Guid Guid { get; set; }
}

// ...
ObservableCollection<Employee> employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
var guid1 = Guid.NewGuid();
employees.Add(new Employee { Name = "Roman", Guid = guid1 });
employees.Add(new Employee { Name = "Oleg", Guid = Guid.NewGuid() });

var x = employees.First(e => e.Guid == guid1);
var index = employees.IndexOf(x); // index = 0, as expected
var result = employees.Remove(x); // result = true, as expected
```

It worked as expected. I would suggest, you set a breakpont at `var x = ...` and check, if

- The collection really contains the item you're looking
- If `First()` really returns that item

Then go to the next line and check, if `index` is returned correctly. And finally check again, if `result` is really false.

I see several possible causes of your code failing:

- You didn't post the full code and something happens between `x=Program.Data.Employees.First()` and `Program.Data.Employees.IndexOf()`
- You use multithreaded code (which also results in "something happening" between the two statements). In this case, you need to synchronize the access to the collection
- You don't use a `ObservableCollection` directly but some derived class instead which is constructed by your data layer (such as `DataServiceCollection`, but this one should work fine too). In this case, check the actual type of your collection in the debugger

Another typical cause of errors with collection would be, if you try to remove items while iterating over the collection (i.e. inside a `foreach`loop): but in this case an exception should be thrown (and `IndexOf` should work fine), so this would only apply if you use some derived class which implements non-standard behaviour.

**EDIT** *(in return to you posting your `Equal` method)*

Your `Equal` method has a serious error in it:

```
String.Equals(other.Patronymic == this.Patronymic, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
... // applies also for following comparisons
```

should be

```
String.Equals(other.Patronymic, this.Patronymic, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
...
```

Also, if you're using a Guid, consider only comparing the GUIDs, since this usually means 'unique identifier', so it should be enough to identify some entity.